# Java sockets not working. Example from Operating Systems Concepts - Abraham Silberschatz

Tags: java, sockets, localhost

I have a question regarding one of the examples in the book. This example  (in the update 8th edition) is in section 3.6, Communication in Client-Server Systems.

I am trying to run the example code in that section, and it doesn't completely work as expected. When I run the code exactly as written in the book, the client requests a socket to be made at the localhost ip address "127.0.0.1". This works fine.

However, when I place the client and server code on different PCs and change my client IP address of the server to contact to "192.xxx.xxx.xxx", the client code just hangs, and no date is returned. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here are the code snippets:

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DateServer
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(6013);

            // now listen for connections
            while(true)
            {
                Socket client = sock.accept();

                PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

                // write the Date to the socket
                pout.println(new java.util.Date().toString());

                // close the socket and resume listening for connections
                client.close();
            }           
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }   

    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DateClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //make connection to server socket
            Socket sock = new Socket("192.xxx.xxx.xxx", 6013);

            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            // read the date from the socket
            String line;
            while ( (line = bin.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            // close the socket connections
            sock.close();       
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Output with IP = "127.0.0.1" :

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Dropbox\practice>java DateClient
Sat Feb 07 22:46:59 PST 2015

C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Dropbox\practice>
```

Output with IP = "192.xxx.xxx.xxx" :

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Dropbox\practice>java DateClient
*nothing here. But program doesn't terminate*
```

Comment: Could be a firewall rule? Start with ping, if successful check port open using nmap, telnet etc. from the client.

Comment: Could be many things, from firewall and to anti-virus. Are the computers on the same LAN? can you ping the server's IP from the client machine?

Comment: Ping works in one direction only. From desktop to laptop. Not from laptop to desktop. The computers are on the same university LAN. I have a switch in between the wall ethernet port, and my two PCs. They are both on the same subnet with mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: Are you asserting that the client really blocks forever? If not, what eventually happens at the client?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't test it forever. But the client hung for a couple minutes. I'll try it again and just leave it on for a while since I'm not working on that problem at the moment. I updated the main post with the outputs I received.

Comment: If the client blocks for more than a few minutes you're going to have to sniff the packets with Wireshark. It would also be useful to know whether it blocked when connecting (unlikely) or when reading.